# jQuery $(document).ready( function()... called on form submit in Rails app, leading to js error?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Minor issue that I noticed in a Rails app that I use for learning new stuff.

I have some simple jQuery that I use to display the time elapsed since a start_time and an end_time on a form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var initial_start = $('#formatted_start_time').val();
    var initial_end   = $('#formatted_end_time').val();
    $("#duration").text(findDuration(initial_start,initial_end));
})
```

The `findDuration()` function simply returns a string that says "1 hour 12 minutes," or something of the ilk based on the contents of the `#formatted_start_time` and `#formatted_end_time` fields. This all works as I would expect.

I noticed that the code fires after I submit the form, however, and Web Inspector shows a single js error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'startTime.split')`, which just refers to the first line in the `findDuration()` function. The 'show' page does not have a `#duration` element, so the code shouldn't fire after submitting (or so I thought).

Why is this code running when I click submit and how do I prevent the error?

**Edit**: The code probably is firing on the 'show' page and not actually when I click submit. The issue seems to be that it is firing on a page with no `#duration` element, as if the show page triggers `$(document).ready...` for the previous page when it lands on the show page.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe this code is running when you click submit; there's absolutely no reason for it to. Where is this code located?

Comment: I got the impression he means it fires on the load of the next page, after the form has submitted. If not, then the whole reasoning behind my answer goes out the window, and we need more of the code, I think :)

Comment: I believe that it fires on the load of the next page, since the error presents on the next page. I don't think that clicking Submit is the issue. I just don't understand why it would fire there if there's no `#duration` element...

Comment: Dave - the code is in in the 3.1 asset pipeline in a file called `activities.js`. It's compiled with the rest of the js when the app launches.

Comment: You'd have to check the jQuery code to find out *why*, but a simple console experiment shows that whatever is passed in to `text` *is* called, even if there are no matching elements... `$("#__un_freaking_likely_id_ohai__").text(alert('foo'));` But I'm with Joe; why include the JavaScript if you don't want it to run?

Comment: Do I have a choice? If it's compiled by the Rails app into the application.js megafile, how do I prevent it other than going with something like Joe's conditional code below? p.s. I'm pretty much a noob with jQuery and still trying to understand the nuances of the new asset pipeline in Rails 3.1. Also: you're right... it's firing on every page. Is there a way to make it conditional based on the presence or absence of a particular element or another method of inserting it into the `div#duration` that is better than `text()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to check the current page, and if it matches the one you want to run this on, run it.

Alternatively, you could just remove the script from the pages you don't want it to run on, which is a much better way to do it :P

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.href == 'http://page.you.want/this/to/run.on') {
        var initial_start = $('#formatted_start_time').val();
        var initial_end   = $('#formatted_end_time').val();
        $("#duration").text(findDuration(initial_start,initial_end));
    }
})
```

Another alternative to check if the `#duration` element exists first;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#duration').length > 0) {
        var initial_start = $('#formatted_start_time').val();
        var initial_end   = $('#formatted_end_time').val();
        $("#duration").text(findDuration(initial_start,initial_end));
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it conditional based on the presence of the `#duration` element or an alternative to `text()` that won't fire on every page?